# Why only BOOL property of AppDelegate is throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, exc-bad-access

In appdelegate.h

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) bool isPhone;
```

In appdelegate.m

```
if ( IDIOM == IPAD ) {
        self.isPhone = NO;
        objDrawing = [[DEDrawingPage alloc]initWithNibName:@"DEDrawingPageiPad" bundle:nil];

    } else {
        self.isPhone = YES;
        objDrawing = [[DEDrawingPage alloc]initWithNibName:@"DEDrawingPageiPhone" bundle:nil];

    }

+(DEAppDelegate *)getDelegate
{
    return (DEAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

In viewController.m

```
if([DEAppDelegate getDelegate].isPhone) // bad access here
    {
        objSettingPage = [[DESettings alloc]initWithNibName:@"DESettingsiPhone" bundle:nil];

    }
```

Accessing `isPhone` property is giving bad access in `IF` condition. This is happening with BOOL type property only. I have tried taking NSNumber or NSString. They are working fine. Why BOOL is giving bad access. I have also tried with (lowercase) bool, that too is useless.

Comment: enable exception break point

Comment: You are aware that iOS can load to appropriate nib file if you use the device file modifier `~ipad` and `~iphone`. Thus `DEDrawingPage~ipad.xib` and  `DEDrawingPage.xib` will do and you do not need to detect the device type.

Comment: that is not my point. For now my problem is different. it is with bad access.

Comment: seems that your getDelegate is the problem..are you using ((DEAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication]).delegate in this getDelegate method?

Comment: They both do the same job(returning reference). I have tried this approach too. I have even NSlogged reference. Reference is coming very well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clean the build and re-check the issue. I have followed the above same steps, didn't get issue.

Also, have you defined below in delegate.h

+(DEAppDelegate *)getDelegate;

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use `macro` of `appDelegate` `object` which is given below to `use` in all your `application` `define` in your `project's` `.pch` `file` :

```
#define appDelegateObject ((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)
```

**Note** : `change` `AppDelegate` to your `Application` `Delegate` `instance`

Use this macro like this :

```
if(appDelegateObject.isPhone) //Here isPhone is property of appDelegate
{
    //anything here
}
```